# URLSession configuration's header setting only work for PUT, not for POST

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm working with NSURLSession default session with the following code

```
  var defaultSession : NSURLSession {
    var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
      // FIXME: for POST this line doesn't work, but for PUT it works, this could be a bug.
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    return NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self.delegate, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
  }
```

But seems like the content-type: application/json setting only works for the PUT method, here is the server resonse

```
POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded /api/v2/DevHiin 400 24.815 ms - 11
PUT application/json /api/v2/DevBoost 201 51.151 ms - 65
```

When I add the header setting for every POST request, it works again.

```
        req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

server

```
POST application/json /api/v2/DevHiin 201 19.925 ms - 95
PUT application/json /api/v2/DevBoost 201 23.729 ms - 65
```

But this is really not a beautiful solution and the code as a whole is really weird, does anybody have the insight to tell me what's going on?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like iOS 8.3 introduced a bug in NSURLSessionConfiguration whereby the specified Content-Type is not being honored (see [NSMutableURLRequest body malformed after iOS 8.3 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528293/nsmutableurlrequest-body-malformed-after-ios-8-3-update) for a similar issue). This brought our entire app to its knees until we implemented a back-end workaround. We also added the Content-Type to each mutable POST request, like you describe.

```
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: One gotcha with this, if you have another process which adds the Content-Type header to the same mutable request object, then using addValue will concatenate the header to something like "application/json,application/json". For that reason, it might be better form to use

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

This will add the header if it doesn't exist, or update it if it does.